# Form align on image using css

Tags: html, css

I am working on a design. The design is located at the link

`http://jodbaki.com/apply-now`.

In it desktop version is working fine but when. I see it in mobile then the form is going out of the image from right side. How can I adjust it ???.

[image]

Comment: Post your relevant CSS and HTML

Comment: Bro there are so many css. You may see the css in inspect elements. I have not posted the css so that the question could be made short

Comment: I suggest to at least try to replicate it in snippet or jsfiddle because once your site gets fixed, this post won't be useful to users who will encounter this problem in the future. Anyway, try applying this to your `entrytext`, `padding: 10px 0px 10px;` and remove the `width: 285px;`  in your `tbody`.

Comment: Create an [mcve] in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
<tbody style="float:right; background:white; margin:12px; width:285px;">
```

should be a class instead. If showing on mobile, the element doesn't change at all. If you have it as a class (with any name, maybe `.applyform`), then you can change the CSS for both your desktop version and the mobile version.

The desktop version, you can copy the tbody styles above and make it a class. For the mobile version, I suggest just changing the float:

```
.applyform { float:none; margin:0; }
```

Without float, your form will be 100% width.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your `input`,`textarea` and `select`. Try adding CSS media query once the width is smaller than 400px, shrink all your fields from 150px to 100px.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {    
  input,textarea,select {
      width: 100px !important;
  }    
}
```